# Android NavigationComponent - Remove fragment after changing activity

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I'm facing an issue concerning the use of navigation component.

**I have this hierarchy :**

- *Activity A* composed of *fragment f1* and *fragment f2*
- *Activity B*

When I'm on f2, I change activity like this :

```
button.setOnClickListener {
        startActivity(Intent(activityA, ActivityB::class.java))
    }
```

**What I would like is :** When I go to activity B, the fragment f2 (of activity A) **should be removed**. So, when I will kill the activity B, I will come back to activity A **without fragment f2**.

To illustrate the flow :

1. Activity A (f1 > f2) > Activity B (**Need to remove f2**)
2. When I will come back : Activity B > Activity A (**f1 only**)

I'm using navigation component and I have tried to use the *popUpTo* and *popUpToInclusive* options in my nav_graph. I managed to remove the fragment but there is always a glitch when I remove it (i.e. we see the removal of fragment before passing the activity B, so we see the f1 fragment a little time). I would like to make the transaction invisible to user.

Is there a way to do it ? Don't hesistate to ask me if you need more precisions.

Thanks for your answers,

Answer (score 0):

When you're using the navigation component, you can have direction, then use the navigation component to move from origin fragment/activity to destination fragment/activity. For example:

```
val actionLockToLogin = LockFragmentDirections.actionLockToLogin()
NavHost.findNavController(this).navigate(actionLockToLogin)
```

In this code, I go from LockFragment, to LoginFragment. Just add the fragments or activities in the navigation's XML. Set an Action from origin fragment / activity to destination fragment / activity. and by using the code I show you, try to navigate between them.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. 
However, I already know how to use it and it's what I used to navigate between fragments. 
My only problem is to remove the f2 fragment which is just before my activity change.